# Webcam upside down when using skype

Tags: 13.04, laptop, skype, webcam, asus

When I use skype my video is upside down. But when I use Google hangouts or cheese it is fine. How do I fix this?

I have tried many things and nothing ever has worked. My laptop is a Asus K53E.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[This is a link](http://m635j520.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/fix-upside-down-skype-video-in-ubuntu.html) to a blog that appears to have solved the upside-down webcam issue on ubuntu 12.10.

First you need to make you have the libv4l-0 package installed.

To install `libv4l-0` open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install libv4l-0
```

If your system is 64-bit then you should specify the i386 architecture, as this is what seems to work with Skype:

```
sudo apt-get install libv4l-0:i386
```

Step 2 is to edit skype.desktop so you can pre-load libv4l-0 with skype so type in terminal: `sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/skype.desktop`

In this file find  `Exec=skype` and replace it with with `Exec=env LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype`

Comment: If your system is 64-bit you should `sudo apt-get install libv4l-0:i386` instead.

Comment: For my 64bit 14.04 machine what worked was `Exec=env PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=60 LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype %U` The original line looked like `Exec=env PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=60 skype %U` . Now the problem is that Webrtc tools for me show upside down: so definately a problem with drivers, not skype. So this should be taken as a patch not a fix.

Comment: Since, the Skype version 8 and above is basically a web app, the trick with `libv4l` will no longer work. I've lost many hours to just find out it's not possible now.  So my solution was extremely straightforward: I've just bought **an external web camera**... and it works flawlessly. Moreover: I finally realized built-in camera in Asus K-series was extremely low quality. The external one is sooo much better.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, this fix does not work with my Asus PC.
The output of above command is:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
```

Eventually, I got the command working from the `README.doc` in `/usr/share/doc`
It was:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l2convert.so skype
```

With an installation of the package:

```
sudo apt-get install libv4l-0:i386
```

Happy :-)

Comment: You really shouldn't ask question within answers. Please delete those parts and only keep the things that help other users to resolve the same problem.