# Ubuntu Camera upside-down

Tags: camera

I use fujitsu lh531 notebook, after I installed ubuntu, my integrated webcam just got upside down.Didn't have any idea what to do, later I realized I should check some external webcams. Tried all possible solutions, but now I used creative 720p webcam which solved the problem.Anybody faced similar problem?

Comment: This might help: [How to fix inverted laptop webcam video](https://askubuntu.com/questions/796082/how-to-fix-inverted-laptop-webcam-video).