# Camera image upside down on Asus K52N

Tags: 18.04, asus, camera

Since I installed Ubuntu on my Asus K52N, my camera images are upside down.

When I used Windows 7 I had this problem, but I installed the Asus Camera driver and it was solved.

How can I resolve this in Ubuntu?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix inverted laptop webcam video](https://askubuntu.com/questions/796082/how-to-fix-inverted-laptop-webcam-video)

Comment: Nope.This is the problem of my camera configuration . Not of viber or google chrome. I do not have any of these