# Camera mirrored on xps 15 with ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dell, 20.04, webcam, camera

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 on a Dell xps 15 7590, with a webcam uvcvideo. My issue is that the camera is mirrored. I tried a few things such as [this](https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=212267) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/796082/how-to-fix-inverted-laptop-webcam-video) but none of it worked. The camera error seems to be on every software (cheese, v4l2 or even [this online webcam test](https://fr.webcamtests.com/)).

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Probably not an ideal solution, but you might be able to unmirror it in the software you use it for. Cheese does have an option that can be turned on or off to mirror the video, and if you record something and later find out it's mirrored, you could use a video editor (or something like ffmpeg) to unmirror it. I guess for programmes like Skype, there might or might not be an option to mirror/unmirror video in the programme.